# Praying behind an Imam

Tags: salat, ruku

My Sister, My father, and I were praying and it was a silent prayer. I was silently reading Surat- Al-Fatiha and My Dad went in Ruku but I was not done reading Fatiha yet.  Because he was leading the prayer I went in to Ruku also. Is this wrong and does it invalidate prayer?

Comment: Please elaborate your post by adding all necessary information like have you fully recited al-Fatihah at least once in the prayer, why you've made ruku' instead of completing recitation and maybe also which maddhab you are following.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the maddhab you are following, each maddhab has a different rulling about reciting *Surat- Al-Fatiha*.

Below is to conclude for each maddhab :

**Hanafi Maddhab :** It is Makruh Tahrim (abominable) on the ma'mum to recite Surah al-Fatihah behind the imam, either in the *sirriyyah* (silent) or *jahriyyah* (loud) prayers, but the ma'mum prayers **remain valid**.

**Maliki Maddhab :** The recitation of Surah al-Fatihah is not absolutely obligatory for the ma'mum either in the *sirriyyah* (silent) or *jahriyyah* (loud) prayers, but it is sunnah for the ma'mum to recite it in the *sirriyyah* (silent) prayers. Ibn al-Arabi from the Malikiyyah scholars made it obligatory for the ma'mum to recite it in the *sirriyyah* (silent) prayer.

**Shafie Maddhab :** The recitation of Surah al-Fatihah is obligatory as a pillar of the ma'mum absolutely. The sunnah is recited during the imam's saktah unless it is feared that the imam will not recite another surah, recite a short surah, or continue to bow, then it is obligatory without makruh to recite al-Fatihah together with the imam.

**Hanbali Maddhab  :** The recitation of Surah al-Fatihah is not obligatory for the ma'mum absolutely but the sunnah for the ma'mum is to recite it in the *sirriyyah* (silent) prayer and during the saktah of the imam. There is a narration from Imam Ahmad that the recitation of al-Fatihah is obligatory (on the ma'mum) in the *sirriyyah* (silent) prayer.

Wallahualam.